# Чтение/запись объектов в текстовый файл

Tags: java

Никак не соображу как записать/считать с текстового файла. В Интернете есть только примеры только с одним объектом. А если такая ситуация как у меня? Мое задание: в программу включить возможность записи данных классов в текстовый файл на диске и чтения их из  текстового файла в программу. Огромное спасибо!

Как прочитать/записать в файл такого вида:

1 Abara 100 true

2 Lilu 100 true

...

Код моей программы:

Zoopark.java:

```
public class Zoopark {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Bassein V1 = new Bassein(2);
        Waterfowl B = new Waterfowl("Vala", 100, true);
        V1.putAnimal(B);
        Waterfowl C = new Waterfowl("Lilu", 100, true);
        V1.putAnimal(C);
        Bird D = new Bird("Abara", 100, true);
        V1.putAnimal(D);

        OpenCage V2 = new OpenCage(4);
        Ungulates E = new Ungulates("Kala", 1000, true);
        V2.putAnimal(E);        
        Ungulates I = new Ungulates("Nala", 1000, true);
        V2.putAnimal(I);
        Ungulates F = new Ungulates("Mala", 1000, true);
        V2.putAnimal(F);
        Ungulates U = new Ungulates("Ala", 1000, true);
        V2.putAnimal(U);

    }

}
```

Animals.java:

```
abstract public class Animals {

    private String name;
    private int weight;
    // is this boy?
    private boolean isMale;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public boolean isMale() {
        return isMale;
    }

    public void setMale(boolean isMale) {
        this.isMale = isMale;
    }

    public Animals(String name, int weight, boolean isMale) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.isMale = isMale;
    }

}
```

Bassein.java

```
public class Bassein extends Valers {

    Bassein(int maxAnimal) {
    super(maxAnimal);
    }

    public void putAnimal(Waterfowl a) {        
    super.putAnimal(a);
    }

    public void putAnimal(Animals a) {      
    //super.putAnimal(a);
    System.out.println("Не тот вид животного");
    } 
}
```

OpenCage.java

```
public class OpenCage extends Valers {

    OpenCage(int maxAnimal) {
    super(maxAnimal);
    }

    public void putAnimal(Ungulates a) {        
    super.putAnimal(a);
    }

    public void putAnimal(Animals a) {      
    //super.putAnimal(a);
    System.out.println("Не тот вид животного");
    } 
}
```

Valers.java

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Valers {

    private int CageLimit;

    List<Animals> result = new ArrayList<Animals>();

    Valers(int maxAnimal) {
        this.CageLimit = maxAnimal;
    }
    public void putAnimal(Animals a) {

        int numAnimals=result.size();

        if (numAnimals>=CageLimit) { 
           System.out.println("Вольер уже полный");
           System.out.println(" ");
        }
        else {
           this.result.add(a);
           System.out.println("Животное добавлено в вольер");
           System.out.println("  ");
        }
    }

    public int getCageAnimals() {
        return result.size();
    }
}
```

Ungulates.java

```
public class Ungulates extends Animals {

    public Ungulates(String name, int weight, boolean isMale) {
        super(name, weight, isMale);
        System.out.println(name + " " + weight + " " + isMale);
    }
}
```

Waterfowl.java

```
public class Waterfowl extends Animals {

    public Waterfowl(String name, int weight, boolean isMale) {
        super(name, weight, isMale);
        System.out.println(name + " " + weight + " " + isMale);
    }
}
```

Comment: если вопрос только в работе с файлами, то помогут классы [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) (создание: `Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));`, методы чтения: чисел — `scanner.nextInt()`, строк — `scanner.next()`) и [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) (создание: `PrintWriter ouput = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));`, методы записи: чисел — `scanner.print(число)`, строк — `scanner.print(строка)`)

Answer (score 1):

Создайте внутри классов методы save и load

```
  public void save(OutputStrem out){
      //в удобном вам порядке записываете свой объект
  }


  public Object load (InputStream in){
     //читаете в том же порядке, что и записывали
  }
```

Либо можете использовать интерфейс serializable и используя ObjectOutputStream писать сразу объект, ObjectInputStream читать объект.

Так же можно использовать xml и json парсеры.

Замечу только, что вариант с serializable не даст вам читаемый для человека файл, остальные вполне читаемы.

В вашем случае вы можете создать методы сохранения загрузки у каждой сущности, а в объектах "бассейн" и "зоопарк" пройтись по всем сущностям и сохранить/загрузить их.

Полезная статья на хабре  https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/60317/